# Generating Unique Numbers of Questions Based on User Input and Collecting input into a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, string.format

**What I am trying to do:**

User is asked How many comedians they want to find.

User inputs 5

User is then prompted with Question 1 in the console stating: "What is Comedian number[1]"
They enter the name and then are prompted with "What is Comedian number[2]" and so forth until Comedian number 5 is inputted...

Lastly, I would like to collect these inputs into a list for later.

So far, the code has gotten to this:

```
Question = int(input("How Many Comedians Do You Want to Find?: "))
lst = list(range(1, Question + 1))

lst_of_input = []
while Question > 0 :
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        iterator = i
    s = input("What is Comedian number {}?: ".format(*iterator))
    if s == "Done":
        break
    lst_of_input.append(s)
print(lst_of_input)
```

Some elements are experimental.  For the purposes of stopping the while loop I included that if Done is inputted then the while loop will break and it will return the values inputted.

The error I receive when running is:

`TypeError: format() argument after * must be an iterable, not int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the error and shorten your code, I'd suggest you make it a `for .. in range()` to loop through the comedians.

The final code would look like this:

```
Question = int(input("How Many Comedians Do You Want to Find?: "))

lst_of_input = []
for question in range(Question) :
    s = input("What is Comedian number {}?: ".format(question+1))
    if s == "Done":
        break
    lst_of_input.append(s)
print(lst_of_input)
```

I have tested it and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been stuck on this issue for days trying to go through documentation and stack overflow but I could not find anything.  I really appreciate it.